# How to join two Hex values c1 and 32 to get decimal of 49458?

Tags: python, hex

im back and have made some progress :)

im trying to join two hex values

for example:
c1 and 32.  In decimal it should be 49458
this is my python code thus far.

```py
ComPort = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity='N',stopbits=1, timeout=1,)

Temphex = b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xC4\x0B'

ComPort.write(Temphex)

temp = ComPort.read(7)
t=" ".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in temp])

print(t)

#parse

t1=(t[12:14])
t2=(t[18:20])
print (t1,t2)

ComPort.close()
```

this is what im getting back

```
t1 = 01 03 04 0a c1 14 32

t2 = c1 32
```

Comment: See the [int built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), using `base = 16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> print( int( (t[12:14]+t[18:20]),16) )
49458
```

Comment: Thanks guess I was overthinking this .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading from a serial port, you're probably better off using `int.from_bytes()` instead and skip all the string conversions. Work with the byte array directly.

I'm not sure what your data looks like but assuming `b'\xc1\x32'` is in your buffer, you'd just do this:

```
int.from_bytes(ComPort.read(2)) # big-endian by default
```

If your data has structure to it, you should use `struct.unpack` or something and give it the format you're expecting.